How to change image for this particle logo effect?
so I came across this code pen (https://codepen.io/srhcdesign/pen/gOJyqRQ) and thought it would be really cool to have on my website. I'm not sure how to change the image from the riot games logo to my own logo, however. i tried changing the url in the JavaScript but it didn't work, the thing didn't show up at all.


window.onload = function() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  let particlesArray = [];
  const numberOfParticles = 1000; // Total number of particles
  const particleSize = 1; // Size of each particle
  const particleSpacing = 1.4; // Spacing between particles for higher density
  const mouseRadius = 70; // Radius of mouse interaction
  const mouse = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    radius: mouseRadius
  };

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
  });

  class Particle {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width; // Random initial x position
      this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height; // Random initial y position
      this.size = particleSize;
      this.color = '#EB0029';
      this.baseX = x;
      this.baseY = y;
      this.density = (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    }
    draw() {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
    }
    update() {
      let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
      let dy = mouse.y - this.y;
      let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      let forceDirectionX = dx / distance;
      let forceDirectionY = dy / distance;
      let maxDistance = mouse.radius;
      let force = (maxDistance - distance) / maxDistance;
      let directionX = (forceDirectionX * force * this.density);
      let directionY = (forceDirectionY * force * this.density);

      if (distance < mouse.radius) {
        this.x -= directionX;
        this.y -= directionY;
      } else {
        if (this.x !== this.baseX) {
          let dx = this.x - this.baseX;
          this.x -= dx / 10;
        }
        if (this.y !== this.baseY) {
          let dy = this.y - this.baseY;
          this.y -= dy / 10;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  async function loadSVG(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "image/svg+xml");
    const paths = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");
    return Array.from(paths).map(path => path.getAttribute("d"));
  }

  function getParticlePositionsFromPathData(pathData) {
    const positions = [];
    const path = new Path2D(pathData);
    const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    const canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    let minX = canvasWidth,
      maxX = 0,
      minY = canvasHeight,
      maxY = 0
    for (let y = 0; y < canvasHeight; y += particleSpacing) { // Adjust spacing for higher density
      for (let x = 0; x < canvasWidth; x += particleSpacing) { // Adjust spacing for higher density
        if (ctx.isPointInPath(path, x, y)) {
          positions.push({
            x,
            y
          });
          if (x < minX) minX = x;
          if (x > maxX) maxX = x;
          if (y < minY) minY = y;
          if (y > maxY) maxY = y;
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      positions,
      minX,
      maxX,
      minY,
      maxY
    };
  }

  async function init() {
    particlesArray = [];
    const svgPaths = await loadSVG('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/5/5b/Riot_Games_2022.svg');

    let allPositions = [];
    let minX = canvas.width,
      maxX = 0,
      minY = canvas.height,
      maxY = 0;


    svgPaths.forEach(pathData => {
      const {
        positions,
        minX: pathMinX,
        maxX: pathMaxX,
        minY: pathMinY,
        maxY: pathMaxY
      } = getParticlePositionsFromPathData(pathData);
      allPositions = allPositions.concat(positions);
      if (pathMinX < minX) minX = pathMinX;
      if (pathMaxX > maxX) maxX = pathMaxX;
      if (pathMinY < minY) minY = pathMinY;
      if (pathMaxY > maxY) maxY = pathMaxY;
    });


    const offsetX = (canvas.width - (maxX - minX)) / 2 - minX;
    const offsetY = (canvas.height - (maxY - minY)) / 2 - minY;

    // Adjust positions to center the SVG
    allPositions = allPositions.map(pos => ({
      x: pos.x + offsetX,
      y: pos.y + offsetY
    }));

    allPositions.forEach(pos => {
      particlesArray.push(new Particle(pos.x, pos.y));
    });
  }

  function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
      particlesArray[i].draw();
      particlesArray[i].update();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

  init();
  animate();
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    init();
  });
};
body {
  background-color: #290000;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>



i tried changing the url from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/5/5b/Riot_Games_2022.svg to https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Vynl_Logo_SVG.svg, but it didn't show up and have the same effect. it just didn't show either logo.

The issue is that the JavaScript wil look for path elements in the SVG document, but the Vynl logo does not have any path elements -- it is just a SVG wrapper around a PNG image of the logo. If you find another SVG containing path elements it will probably work. Another approach would be to rewrite the JavaScript so that any SVG could be drawn on the canvas element.

could you please provide an example of how to rewrite the javascript?

You change the url for the loadSVG() function at line 101. Please try const svgPaths = await loadSVG('https://assets.codepen.io/222579/bone.svg');

sorry for not clarifying. I was asking for how to rewrite so any svg could be drawn, not just the ones with path elements.
